# Remove a word next to search string

Tags: sed

How do I remove exactly 1 word after the search string?
I am able to delete the search word but not the word after that i.e. "utf8"

```
# echo "varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8,"
varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8,

# echo "varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8," |  sed 's/ CHARACTER SET[^ ]* / /g'
varchar(255) utf8,
```

expected output:

```
varchar(255) ,
```

Comment: In some cases there can be 2 words after the search string and I need to remove both. for e.g. utf8 ansi

Comment: See my answer below. It handles any number of words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8," |  sed 's/ CHARACTER SET [[:alnum:]]\+/ /g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean this?

```
echo "varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8," |  sed 's/ CHARACTER SET[ a-z0-9,]*/ /g'
```

**Output**

```
varchar(255)
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
echo "varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8," |  sed 's/ CHARACTER SET \w*/ /g'
```

Answer (score 0):

echo "varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8, aa" |  sed 's/ CHARACTER SET.*,/ /g'